# Cant get port when accept with sockaddr_storage - ipv6

Tags: port, ipv6, ipv4

I can not get port number when i accept with  sockaddr_storage in ipv6.
Here is my v4 code:

```
peersockfd = accept(xtcpsock_fd,(struct sockaddr*)&addr,(socklen_t*)&len);
.....
sprintf(szSocket,"%s:%d",inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr),ntohs(addr.sin_port));
```

I am trying to do the same thing for v6 but sockaddr_storage doesn't have any member as port. How can i do that?

```
peersockfd = accept(xtcpsock6_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
.....           
inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family, &((struct sockaddr_in6 *)&their_addr)->sin6_addr,s,sizeof s);
sprintf(szSocket,"%s:%d",s,***ntohs(their_addr.sin_port));
```

Answer (score 1):

For IPv6 you need to cast to **sockaddr_in6** and then the member is named **sin6_port** rather than sin_port.